# Find partial text within separate cells. Then set an integer value based on results.

Tags: excel, vba

I have to find partial text within two cells of the same row and same sheet. The partial text within the cells do not have to match each other, they must match a separate text string that is specific to the column.
For example;

```
   Col A text          Col D text       Col E value
R1 xxxxBOXxxxx         xxxxBAGxxxx     
R2  xBOXxxxxx          xxxxxxxxBAGxx
```

BOX is unique to Col A, BAG is unique to Col D. The position of the partial text may appear anywhere within the cell. If the text conditions match, assign Col E same row, a value 1, no match no value. The search/find will continue throughout the sheet

I'm not sure how to approach this task; search, find, match, vlookup, etc.
Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What are the expected results? Is it 1 and 1 or 1 and nothing? I'm unclear on whether the second string's position within column D should match the first string's position within column A or if position is unimportant and only existence is the criteria.

Comment: The position is unimportant, only the appearance. It is basically a Boolean 'and'. If ColA R1(1,1) has BOX and ColD(1,4) has BAG then Col D R1 (1,5) = 1. No other conditions matter, continue the same search and match throughout the sheet, same columns.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting a Row1 for convenience with `BOX` in B1 and `BAG` in D1, in E3 and copied down to suit:

```
 =--(AND(MATCH("*"&B$1&"*",B3,0),MATCH("*"&D$1&"*",D3,0)))
```

should return `1` where each value is present in the appropriate column for that row and `#N/A` otherwise.